# Adjust text autotable jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using JSPDF Autotable, but I have a problem, I can not find a way to adjust the text of the cells.

There is some property to adjust the text (vertical, horizontal) of the cells.

[Link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lApQT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align text with the styles `halign` and `valign` https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#styles

Comment: If the cell text is too large it does not come out complete, as I make the text continue one line down and display all the content.

Comment: `overflow: 'linebreak'` :) ty